# fprintf() to a csv file in C by using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure defined like this

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char* name;
    float percentage;
}student_t;
```

And there is a function that is to print struct's member in this format

```
"id, name, percentage\n"
```

But the function takes in `void* val_ref //struct ptr, void* fp`
How do I make it work? The function looks like this (paramters are given cannot be modified)

```
void printStudentInfo(void* val_ref, void* fp)
{
    if (val_ref != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d,%s,%.2f", val_ref->id, val_ref->name, val_ref->percentage);
    }
}
```

But I can't compile, it says warning: deferencing void* pointer
error: request for memeber "id" in something not a struct or union
error: request for memeber "name" in something not a struct or union
error: request for memeber "percentage" in something not a struct or union

Do I have to do type cast for parameter val_ref?

Comment: Yes, you have to typecast the void pointer back. Or just change the function prototype to take a `student_t*` and a `FILE*` instead of 2 `void*` parameters. Why does it take void pointers to begin with? Is it a given function?

Comment: @LouisCloete yeah its a given function, I cannot modify the parameters But also when I do typecast like ```student_t* val_ref```, compiler would tell me that ```redeclare as a different kind of symbol and previous defined in function parameter```

Comment: It pointless to use void pointers here, just use the appropriate pointer types.

Comment: `val_ref->id, val_ref->name, val_ref->percentage` -> `((student_t*)val_ref)->id, ((student_t*)val_ref)->name, ((student_t*)val_ref)->percentage`

Comment: I agree with @Jabberwocky. What was the question? The only way void pointers make sense is if it should be "generic" by being able to take more than one struct type and more than one output handle type and output the generic struct to the generic output handle.

Comment: @AlexHu note the parentheses around the type in a cast. `student_t * val_ref` and `(student_t*) val_ref` are 2 completely different things.

Comment: Do I need to do the same for ```void* fp``` as well?

Comment: @AlexHu yes, obviously

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you

Comment: I suppose this is an exercise and the purpose is to learn what type casts are, but this is a particularly bad use case as mentioned in some comments.

Comment: I mean simple typecast like (float) int wouldn't make me learn anything tho, Also for the line says ```if (val_ref != NULL)``` do I have to typecast it too?? Otherwise what would Val_ref points at if I didn't typecast in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprintf(fp, "%d,%s,%.2f", val_ref->id, val_ref->name, val_ref->percentage);` Over here, you need to cast `val_ref` to the type of pointer it actually is: `(student_t *)val_ref` and then fetch a member of the struct for e.g. `((student_t*)val_ref)->id`.

When you have a `void*`, your program does not know the actual data type you are pointing to. Hence, it is illegal to try to fetch a member. Upon using a cast, you are explicitly saying that `val_ref` points to a `student_t` and you know what you are doing when you ask for a specific member.

However, there is no need to cast `fp` because the function `fprintf` has the first argument as `FILE *` in it's signature:

`int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);`

So, even if you pass a `void *` as the first parameter, the local variable `stream` is defined as a `FILE *` and that's what the function works with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do I have to typecast in ```if``` statement?

Comment: @AlexHu No. Comparison of a `void *` with `NULL` is well defined.

Comment: Appreciate the reply